# Null message on hTTPResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result after 1st foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient, httpresponsemessage, getasync

I have issue with null result messages when calling a HttpClient getAsync within a foreach loop.

I need to iterate with a list of objects for values to call an API via HttpClient. After the first loop, the HttpResponseMessage's result() comes up with null message.

I tried CacheControl.NoCache = true. It's not working.

```
public async Task<List<Common.ProgressResponse>> RunAsync()
{
    List<Response> ListOfResponses = new List<Responses>();

    try
    {
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri([URL]);
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue() { NoCache = true };
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add([KEY], [VALUE]);

        ListOfResponses = await SomeFunction();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Exceptions here...
    }
    return ListOfResponses;
}


private async Task<List<ListOfResponses>> SomeFunction()
{
    List<Response> responses = new List<Response>();
    string aPISuffix = string.Format("{0}/{1}", [APISUFFIX1], [APISUFFIX2]);

    foreach (Object obj in ListOfObject)
    {
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Param1", obj.Param1);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Param2))
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Param2", obj.Param2);

        Response response = new Response();


/*This is where the issue is .begin.*/
        HttpResponseMessage hTTPResponse = await _client.GetAsync(aPISuffix).ConfigureAwait(false);
        string result = hTTPResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
/*This is where the issue is .end.*/


        if (hTTPResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            response = [Code here...]
            //Codes here...
        }

        responses.Add(response);
    }

    return responses;
}
```

On: 'string result = hTTPResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;'
I would expect the result message would have values as it loops through ListOfObjects.

Comment: Why are you using `await` everywhere, but suddenly [`.Result`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) on that one line?

Comment: You should check the httpResponse status code BEFORE reading the content. You might see some surprises. I can't see how the httpclient is being initiated, but I'd be careful about resetting the default headers, and instead I'd try to specify them on a per request basis in order to avoid multiple requests conflicting with each others

Comment: coz the calling functions are all asynchronous...

Comment: @ESG the httpClient is a static global in the class. The class gets instantiated with a using() statement.

Comment: @praetorean be careful with static httpclients too.  If you register this class as a singleton, then your DNS entries will get stale.

Comment: Solved it... I moved the .DefaultRequestHeaders values inside the foreach() loop. I suspected that they were pilling up at every loop iteration. I had to clear them and set them up before the GetAsync()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it... I moved the .DefaultRequestHeaders values inside the foreach() loop. 
I suspected that they were pilling up at every loop iteration. I had to clear them and set them up before the GetAsync()

Updated code here:

```
public async Task<List<Common.ProgressResponse>> RunAsync()
{
    List<Response> ListOfResponses = new List<Responses>();

    try
    {
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri([URL]);
        ListOfResponses = await SomeFunction();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Exceptions here...
    }
    return ListOfResponses;
}


private async Task<List<ListOfResponses>> SomeFunction()
{
    List<Response> responses = new List<Response>();
    string aPISuffix = string.Format("{0}/{1}", [APISUFFIX1], [APISUFFIX2]);

    foreach (Object obj in ListOfObject)
    {
        /*Moved Code .begin.*/
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue() { NoCache = true };
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add([KEY], [VALUE]);      

        /*Moved Code .end.*/

        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Param1", obj.Param1);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Param2))
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Param2", obj.Param2);

        Response response = new Response();
        HttpResponseMessage hTTPResponse = await _client.GetAsync(aPISuffix).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (hTTPResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string result = hTTPResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;        
            response = [Code here...]
            //Codes here...
        }

        responses.Add(response);
    }

    return responses;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly why I like to use the HttpRequestMessage.  Have to clear headers seems a bit odd.  IMHO - the code is clearer by adding it to the message.  It’s also easier to unit test.

Answer (score 4):

**Update: Per comment**

First off, I generally try to avoid using .Result with tasks.  I also don't think adding the cache headers is the issue since you are making a server to server call.

One thing I tend to always do is evaluate the response before I try to read it.  I also prefer to use the HttpRequestMessage so I can manage the disposal of it.

Here is a quick example demonstrating how call out:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task TestAsync()
        {
            var urls = new string[]
            {
                "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57084989/null-message-on-httpresponse-content-readasstringasync-result-after-1st-foreac",
                "https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025711/rogala"
            };

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                foreach (var url in urls)
                {
                    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Request: {url}".PadLeft(5,'*').PadRight(5, '*'));
                        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request)
                            .ConfigureAwait(false);

                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                            .ConfigureAwait(false);
                            Console.WriteLine($"{body.Length}{Environment.NewLine}");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"*Bad request: {response.StatusCode}");
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

One additional thing to keep in mind is socket exhaustion.  If this code is running on a server, then you will run into socket exhaustion once your service gets some load.  I would highly recommend using an [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to handle the HttpClients.

With respect to why the content string is empty, it could be because the server didn't return content which could be a server issue.  The server may have also throttled you, which resulted in no content.  I would recommend looking into [Polly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/polly) to handle certain response codes.

Comment: What? This doesn't really answer the question, You just fixed some of the minor bugs.  If you're claim that using .Result is the issue explain why.

Comment: No, I am showing the pattern that does work.  As mentioned in a comment, you should not attempt to read the body before checking the result.  Additionally, this pattern is different in that a new HttpRequestMessage is generated and sent vs calling get.  Finally, I could be wrong here, but the caching is not needed for server to server calls.

Comment: That comment should be the first part of your answer.  If you read this answer from a users part of view its unclear on how or why this would fix this issue